# Delay ajax call for minified file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, nopcommerce

I'm working with the seven spikes nop commerce ajax filters plugin.
I would like to delay the ajax request by 2 seconds, but nothing seems to work.
 - I have tried jquery delay.
 - I managed to get sleep function that returns a promise working, but it doesn't work in IE.
 - I have tried setTimeout, but for some reason it breaks the plugin.

Here is the bit of code I'm looking at from the Filters.min.js file:

```
function c(i, a, o, s, c, p, u) {
            if (!r.waitForAjaxRequest && "#/noFilterApplied" !== s) {
                this.isProductRefreshTriggeredByScroll = u || !1, void 0 == s ? s = "" : p = !0, this.setSpecificationFilterSelection(i, a);
                var f = this.getSpecificationFiltersModel(),
                    h = this.getAttributeFiltersModel(),
                    g = this.getManufacturerFiltersModel(),
                    v = this.getVendorFiltersModel(),
                    S = this.getOnSaleFiltersModel(),
                    F = this.getPriceRangeFilterModel();
                void 0 == o && (o = null);
                var P = e(".sortOptionsDropDown").val() || e(".nopAjaxFilters7Spikes").attr("data-defaultsortoption") || null,
                    A = d(),
                    x = e(".productsPageSizeDropDown").val() || null,
                    k = t.getUrlVar("pageNumber");
                void 0 == k || null != o || void 0 != c && c !== !1 || (o = k), void 0 == p && (p = !1);
                var m = {
                    categoryId: this.categoryId,
                    manufacturerId: this.manufacturerId,
                    vendorId: this.vendorId,
                    priceRangeFilterModel7Spikes: F,
                    specificationFiltersModel7Spikes: f,
                    attributeFiltersModel7Spikes: h,
                    manufacturerFiltersModel7Spikes: g,
                    vendorFiltersModel7Spikes: v,
                    pageNumber: o,
                    orderby: P,
                    viewmode: A,
                    pagesize: x,
                    queryString: s,
                    shouldNotStartFromFirstPage: p,
                    onSaleFilterModel: S,
                    keyword: this.keyword,
                    searchCategoryId: this.searchCategoryId,
                    searchManufacturerId: this.searchManufacturerId,
                    priceFrom: this.priceFrom,
                    priceTo: this.priceTo,
                    includeSubcategories: this.includeSubcategories,
                    searchInProductDescriptions: this.searchInProductDescriptions,
                    advancedSearch: this.advancedSearch,
                    isOnSearchPage: this.isOnSearchPage
                };
                this.isProductRefreshTriggeredByScroll || this.showProductPanelAjaxBusy();
                var C = this,
                    y = this.getFilteredProductsUrl;
                r.waitForAjaxRequest = !0, e.ajax({
                    cache: !1,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: e.toJSON(m),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: y
                }).done(function(t) {
                    "" !== s && (C.changeViewModeOrderByAndPageSize(t), C.setPriceRangeValues(t));
                    var i = C.refreshProducts(t, C.isProductRefreshTriggeredByScroll);
                    if (!i) return void(r.waitForAjaxRequest = !1);
                    if (C.refreshFilters(t), C.refreshProductsPager(t), C.refreshClearButtons(), "NO HASH QUERY" !== s) {
                        C.expandFilterPanelsWithSelectedOptions();
                        var a = e(t).filter("#urlHashQuery").val().toString();
                        "" !== a ? (C.isProductRefreshTriggeredByScroll && (a = a.slice(0, a.indexOf("&pageNumber"))), e.address.value(a)) : e.address.value("noFilterApplied")
                    }
                    C.hideProductPanelAjaxBusy(), r.waitForAjaxRequest = !1;
                    var o = e(".nopAjaxFilters7Spikes").attr("data-scrollToElement");
                    if (!C.isProductRefreshTriggeredByScroll && void 0 != o && "true" === o.toLowerCase()) {
                        var d = e(".nopAjaxFilters7Spikes").attr("data-scrollToElementSelector"),
                            c = d.split(","),
                            p = ".product-selectors";
                        if (void 0 != c && c.length > 0) {
                            for (var u = 0; u < c.length; u++)
                                if (e(c[u].trim()).length > 0) {
                                    p = c[u].trim();
                                    break
                                }
                            e(p).length > 0 && e("html, body").animate({
                                scrollTop: e(p).offset().top
                            }, "slow")
                        }
                    }
                    e(".productPanelAjaxBusy").length < 1 && C.addProductPanelAjaxBusyToPage();
                    var f = e(t).filter("#totalCount").val().toString();
                    if (e.event.trigger({
                            type: "nopAjaxFiltersFiltrationCompleteEvent",
                            totalCount: f
                        }), "true" === e(".nopAjaxFilters7Spikes").attr("data-showSelectedFiltersPanel").toLowerCase() && l(), "true" !== e(".nopAjaxFilters7Spikes").attr("data-enableinfinitescroll").toLowerCase() && "false" !== e(".nopAjaxFilters7Spikes").attr("data-numberofreturnedproductsselector").toLowerCase()) {
                        var h = x;
                        e(".page-body .product-grid:not(.featured-product-grid)").length > 0 ? h = e(".page-body .product-grid:not(.featured-product-grid) .item-box").length : e(".page-body .product-list").length > 0 && (h = e(".page-body .product-list .item-box").length), n(h, f)
                    }
                }).fail(function() {
                    C.hideProductPanelAjaxBusy(), alert("Loading the page failed."), r.waitForAjaxRequest = !1
                }).always(function() {
                    C.isProductRefreshTriggeredByScroll = !1
                })
            }
        }
```

I tried wrapping the if statement inside the function inside setTimeout like this:

```
function c(i, a, o, s, c, p, u) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!r.waitForAjaxRequest && "#/noFilterApplied" !== s) {  
...
```

Also tried this:

```
function sleep(ms) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function c(i, a, o, s, c, p, u) {
    await sleep(2000);
....
```

Not really sure how to go about this, any ideas?
Cheers

### Update based on comments

***1*** There were no errors at all in console, basically by stopped working I mean the ajax call that is triggered on a filter change would not trigger and nothing would happen. Errors are the first thing I look for which is why I'm stumped.

***2*** Using the sleep promise code the filters work fine, so adding a delay doesn't cause an issue.

***3*** The reason I want to modify this is let's say I have 10 checkboxes, and I want to choose 3. So I click the 3 checkboxes but as soon as I click the first checkbox the ajax call is sent and the other two checkbox filters are not used. This is the way the plugin was released.

***DEMO*** to get the idea go to [this demo](http://demos.nop-templates.com/computers) and open up dev tools and throttle connection speed to GPRS, then try and select 2 checkboxes an you will see you can't. I would like the delay so users can select 2 or 3 checkboxes before the ajax call is sent. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Could you update your code samples to use 2 space indentation? It’s quite unreadable as-is

Comment: @Geuis The first bit of code is minified, so will be unreadable.

Comment: Ah right. Gotcha.

Comment: Why didn't the `setTimeout()` work?  That would certainly delay executing for the duration of the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm really not sure, but just by adding that timeout function stopped the whole plugin from working. I would have though it would have worked too but for some reason it didn't

Comment: "Stopped plugin from working" isn't very specific.  Did you introduce a syntax error?  Did you trace through the code in the debugger?  Does the code rely on something happening immediately?  There doesn't appear to be any return value from the function so I don't think there's any code relying on that.  There could be side effects that are supposed to happen immediately (but that's not something we can easily tell in minimized code).

Comment: Also, why are you trying to introduce this delay?  This smells like it may be a work-around to some other problem when the right answer is to properly fix the other problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 see the bottom of question for update, should give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. Normally I can figure this stuff out but this one has me stumped.
Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't have the energy to work on minimized code with all meaningless variable names.  You could fix this with your own code attached to the checkboxes much simpler than messing with this code.